# Background process in android

Tags: android

I would like read the file and upload to server in the background which is not require any interaction with the user.which concept is suitable for this?
1.IntentService
2.Async Task
3.Service

please suggest me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think service is better option because it runs in background and suitable for long running background process such as I/O Operation . Service might handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use standard java Thread for this.